# Restrict User To Enter Same range of values against a particular type

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, asp.net

I have a dynnamic grid in which user can add as many rows as he wants. On addition of rows, he will select a type, and against that type will enter a minimum value and a maximum value.

```
     Type    Minimum Value  MaximumValue   AddRow
      ABC        12            13          (icon)
      XYZ        12            13          (icon)
      ABC        12            13          (icon)
```

Here is an example. The user selects type ABC and enters the ranges. In second row , the user has selected a different type and enters the ranges. In the third row, the user has selected a type and enters the same ranges as the first row. The same type can not have the same range again. moreover, there should be no overlapping as well. So on saving I want to do something to restrict the user to not enter the same range against that type if he has already entered once before. I am confused as How can I do this?

So Far this is what I have done for the validation.

```
                if (map.has(CustomerTypeCode)) {
                    var obj = map.get(CustomerTypeCode);
                    if (minVal >= obj.minVal && maxVal <= obj.maxVal) {
                        alert("Duplicate Ranges Found!");
                    }
                } else {
                map.set(type, {
                    minVal: minVal,
                    maxVal: maxVal
                  })
                }
```

Comment: @Andrew Myres Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to achieve what you want.

```
//You must declare your map at global scope or outer scope of this operation 
//so that you don't create new map every time
const map = new Map();

let minVal = $(this).find("td:eq(3)").find("input").val();
let maxVal = $(this).find("td:eq(4)").find("input").val();
// I don't know your html so I assume you can get selected type
let type = "ABC";
if (map.has(type)) {
  let obj = map.get(type);
  if (minVal >= obj.minVal && maxVal <= obj.maxVal) {
    alert("Duplicate Ranges Found!");
  }
} else {
  map.set(type, {
    minVal: minVal,
    maxVal: maxVal
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi let me try and see if this works. This will also prevent overlapping as well? @Burhan Savci

Comment: Yes, it also checks the overlap values you mentioned in the question.

Comment: My code is not supprting this const variable.Is there any alternative?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean when you say my code doesn't support it. However, in JS you can define your variables as [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). You can use one of these

Comment: It gives me Map is undefined. Can you please help?

Comment: I also want to show red borders around those textboxes for which duplicates were found.

Comment: I don't know exactly how your codes in the script tag are, but you need to define the map like this `<script>
    const map = new Map();
    function OnSave(){
        //... code goes here
    }
</script>`
Also, you need to pay attention to the case sensitivity of the variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240069/discussion-between-unknown-and-burhan-savci).